# How to manipulate $index on UI

Tags: knockout.js

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: users"> 
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $index"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>  
</tbody>
```

As $index is 0 based, currently it displays 0 name. I need to start from 1, I did try below code

```
<td data-bind="text: $index + 1"></td>
```

Comment: For display purposes only? Read the observable value by using `()`. So it would become `<td data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$index` as an observable if you don't want just the value, e.g.:

```
<td data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></td>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhQ2U/).

The [KO documentation on binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) has the relevant info, too (emphasis mine):

> `$index` (only available within `foreach` bindings)
>
> This is the zero-based index of the current array entry being rendered by a `foreach` binding. Unlike the other binding context properties, **`$index` is an observable** and is updated whenever the index of the item changes (e.g., if items are added to or removed from the array).